# Fastest way to compare list of lists against list of sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance

Is there a faster way to do the following list comprehension?

```py
ret = [
    [
        subList 
        for subList in lst 
        if set(subList) not in listOfSets
    ] 
    for lst in listOfLists
]
```

**Restrictions**

- `listOfSets`: None
- `listOfLists`: Must maintain the ordering of the subsublists during construction, but not necessarily the ordering of the sublists. I.e:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9]]] != [[[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4]], [7, 8, 9]]
```

but

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9]]] = [[[7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

- `ret`: `ret` must maintain the same ordering of the original `listOfLists` as detailed above.

---

My code generates the following list of lists. Each list contains equally sized sublists but the number of sublists van vary. I.e.:

```py
listOfLists = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 5], [9, 8, 7]], [[11, 12, 13]], ...]
```

I need to filter this list of lists to remove all sublists that do not exist in a list of sets:

```
listOfSets = [{1, 2, 3}, {20, 30, 15}, {6, 7, 8}, ...]

ret = [
    [
        subList 
        for subList in lst 
        if set(subList) not in listOfSets
    ] 
    for lst in listOfLists
]

ret = [[[4, 6, 5], [9, 8, 7]], [[11, 12, 13]], ...]
```

Note the missing `[1, 2, 3]` in ret.

I have tried variations of the following

```py
ret = [
    [
        subList 
        for subList in lst 
        if not(set(subList) in listOfSets)
    ] for lst in listOfLists
]
```

with the idea being that `not(set(subList) in listOfSets)` will return faster since it need only find a single match, but to no avail:

```
%timeit ret = [
    [
        subList 
        for subList in lst 
        if set(subList) not in listOfSets
    ] 
    for lst in listOfLists
]
772 µs ± 26.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit ret = [
    [
        subList 
        for subList in lst 
        if not(set(subList) in listOfSets)
   ] for lst in listOfLists
]
797 µs ± 38.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Are the types of these containers open to change? i.e. could your `listoflists` be a list of tuples, and could your `listofsets` be a set of tuples?

Comment: `listOfSets` can be changed entirely, and the only restriction on `ret` (and therefore `listOfLists`) is that it must maintain the ordering of the sublists of the original `listOfLists`.

Comment: Is the reason for using a list of sets because you don't care about the order of elements in the innermost sublists? i.e. [1,2,3] can be included if {3,2,1} is in your list of sets?

Comment: Yes, (and because the list comparison proved to be ever so slightly faster when they were all sets) but the final form *must* still preserve the original ordering.

Comment: How large are your lists/sets?

Comment: `listOfSets` is guaranteed to be enormous, but `listOfLists` can be as few as a handful of lists total or ~100. As a rule, `listOfSets` is *always* bigger than `listOfLists`.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried `range(enormous)`, but Python complained `NameError: name 'enormous' is not defined` :-(

Comment: In other words, if I try to write a benchmark to check whether / how much something helps, I need to enter actual numbers.

Comment: Weird... it worked on my machine :)! For that particular sizes I am benchmarking `listOfSets` is 2680 sets large, and `listOfLists` is at most ~10 lists in total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Original Answer

I will not extend so much, given that the other answer is already very complete, but I got even better performance by using the difference between sets.

Let:

```py
>>> set_of_tuples = {(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 7), (11, 12, 13), (6, 7, 8)}
>>> list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[(1, 2, 3), (4, 6, 5), (9, 8, 7)], [(11, 12, 13)]]
```

For comparison, here is JJ Hassan's second example run on my machine (plus, note that I included the `not in` that was in the original question):

```py
>>> filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[sl for sl in l if sl in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
>>> filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples
[[(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 7)], [(11, 12, 13)]]
>>> %timeit -n1000000 -r7 filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[sl for sl in l if sl not in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
930 ns ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Now, using the difference between sets:

```py
>>> filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = [set(l) - set_of_tuples for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
>>> filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples
[{(4, 6, 5)}, set()]
>>> %timeit -n1000000 -r7 filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = [set(l) - set_of_tuples for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
864 ns ± 63.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Try this option as well, as I believe that the difference in speed may become more significant with bigger lists.

The idea behind this is that you have a **superlist**, which is a list of **lists**, each containing a **sublist**, or in this case a `tuple`. But, as per your requirements, the intermediate **lists** do not need to preserve order (only the **superlist** and the **sublists**), and we want to take those elements that are not found in `set_of_tuples`. Consequently, the intermediate **lists** can be seen as `set`s, and the operation of taking the elements that do not belong to `set_of_tuples` is trivially the difference between sets.

### Edit

I just came up with a slightly faster solution by using `functools` and `itertools`. This new solution, however, is better only when we enough data.

Let us start with the previous solution:

```py
filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = [set(l) - set_of_tuples for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
```

Now, by a simple application of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), this becomes:

```py
filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = [s - set_of_tuples for s in map(set, list_of_lists_of_tuples)]
```

Then we can use [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub) to rewrite this as:

```py
from operator import sub
filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = [sub(s, set_of_tuples) for s in map(set, list_of_lists_of_tuples)]
```

or, using a plain `list`:

```py
from operator import sub
filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = list(sub(s, set_of_tuples) for s in map(set, list_of_lists_of_tuples))
```

Finally, we use `map` once more, this time bringing [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to the game:

```py
from itertools import repeat
from operator import sub

filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = list(map(sub, map(set, list_of_lists_of_tuples), repeat(set_of_tuples)))
```

This new method is actually the slowest given small lists:

```py
>>> set_of_tuples = {(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 7), (11, 12, 13), (6, 7, 8)}
>>> list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[(1, 2, 3), (4, 6, 5), (9, 8, 7)], [(11, 12, 13)]]
>>> %timeit -n1000000 -r20 filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[sl for sl in l if sl not in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
903 ns ± 168 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -n1000000 -r20 filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = [set(l) - set_of_tuples for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
789 ns ± 70 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -n1000000 -r20 filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = list(map(sub, map(set, list_of_lists_of_tuples), repeat(set_of_tuples)))
1.28 µs ± 299 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

But now let us define bigger lists. I used approximately the sizes you mentioned in a comment:

```py
>>> from random import randint
>>> list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[(1, 2, 3), (4, 6, 5), (9, 8, 7)], [(11, 12, 13)]] * 100
>>> set_of_tuples = {(randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100)) for _ in range(2680)}
```

Using this new data, here are the results I got on my machine:

```py
>>> %timeit -n10000 -r20 filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[sl for sl in l if sl not in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
65 µs ± 7.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -n10000 -r20 filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = [set(l) - set_of_tuples for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
58.1 µs ± 6.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -n10000 -r20 filtered_list_of_sets_of_tuples = list(map(sub, map(set, list_of_lists_of_tuples), repeat(set_of_tuples)))
54.1 µs ± 5.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: You are correct, this method is faster: `2.09 µs ± 42.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`. I will mark this as correct answer then

Comment: I love it! But this gives us a list of sets of tuples at the end (as shown in the var name), so it doesn't preserve the type of **intermediate list** ? It's a really cool solution but it does change the behaviour a bit

Comment: By the way, if you're okay with the intermediate container being a set at the end, you can also filter out empty sets in the result with `list_of_sets_of_tuples = [y for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples if (y := set(l) & set_of_tuples)]` (or `-` for a negative membership test) (python 3.8+ only for use of assignment expression (walrus))

Comment: Interesting that the edit is only faster for very large lists. +1 for the extra effort though, I only have but 1 upvote to give...

Answer (score 3):

**Note: the last example here is closest to a speed increase on your example, but the first two might be useful as they're even faster although they change the behaviour slightly. *tl;dr change your list of sets to a set of frozensets for faster membership checks***

You mention that your list of sets can be changed to find an ideal solution, so I'd suggest using a set of something hashable like `tuple`s, or (in the last example) `frozenset`s. The type of membership test you're doing is much faster when using sets like I do in these examples.

**Example 1: Using tuples with casts**

In this example we convert the sub-sub-lists to tuples, and use a set of tuples. This is better because tuples are hashable and we can have a set of them. Sets are the best container for membership checks.

```py
set_of_tuples = {(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 7), (11, 12, 13), (6, 7, 8)}

list_of_lists_of_lists = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 5], [9, 8, 7]], [[11, 12, 13]]]

filtered_list_of_lists_of_lists =  [[sl for sl in l if tuple(sl) in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_lists]

filtered_list_of_lists_of_lists
# >> [[[1, 2, 3], [9, 8, 7]], [[11, 12, 13]]]

# %timeit filtered_list_of_lists_of_lists =  [[sl for sl in l if tuple(sl) in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_lists]
# 691 ns ± 91.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**Example 2: Using tuples without casts**

if we're allowed to consume a `list_of_lists_of_tuples` instead it becomes even faster because we don't have to cast the lists

```py
set_of_tuples = {(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 7), (11, 12, 13), (6, 7, 8)}

list_of_lists_of_tuples = [[(1, 2, 3), (4, 6, 5), (9, 8, 7)], [(11, 12, 13)]]

filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples =  [[sl for sl in l if sl in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]

filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples
# >> [[(1, 2, 3), (9, 8, 7)], [(11, 12, 13)]]

# %timeit filtered_list_of_lists_of_tuples =  [[sl for sl in l if sl in set_of_tuples] for l in list_of_lists_of_tuples]
# >> 474 ns ± 58.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

This assumes that the order of the sub-sub-list/tuple is important though, as it changes the behaviour of your code slightly. In your code a sub-sub-list of `[1,2,3]` would be included if the set `{3,1,2}` was in your list of sets because `set([1,2,3]) == {3,1,2}`.

**Example 3: Using frozensets**

If we wanted to preserve that behaviour then we can use frozenset which is also hashable! We'll use a set of frozensets.

```py
set_of_frozen_sets = {frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([9,8,7]), frozenset([11,12,13]), frozenset([6,7,9])}

list_of_lists_of_lists = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 5], [9, 8, 7]], [[11, 12, 13]]]

filtered_list_of_lists_of_lists =  [[sl for sl in l if frozenset(sl) in set_of_frozen_sets] for l in list_of_lists_of_lists]

filtered_list_of_lists_of_lists
# >> [[[1, 2, 3], [9, 8, 7]], [[11, 12, 13]]]

# %timeit filtered_list_of_lists_of_lists =  [[sl for sl in l if frozenset(sl) in set_of_frozen_sets] for l in list_of_lists_of_lists]
# >> 1.13 µs ± 92.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

which appears to take a fair bit longer than the first two examples (I suppose the conversion to frozenset from list is bit more expensive).

Please try those and see if you notice the same speed increases on your machine.

Note: One other possible difference in behaviour is my code will leave an empty sublist in the return value if no sub-sub-lists in that sublist match

Comment: Of the methods you mentioned, example 2 is certainly fastest so far. I get the following timings: `2.64 µs ± 50.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`. `len(listOfSets) = 2688`, and `listOfLists = [[3]x[2]x[3]]`

Comment: Yeah, looking at your comments above I tried this with a `set` of `tuple`s or `frozenset`s 2680 long and a listoflists of around 10 sublists of lists and it took around that much time.

Comment: Also, apologies for the verbosity of the answer! For better or worse I ended up showing my working. In general though, refactoring membership tests so that you can use `set` as the container of valid values will get you significant speed boosts over using a list (O(1) vs O(n)).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why I didn't think to go the step further of making the `listOfSets` into a `setOfXXX`... it doesn't even start out as a list of sets, but also as a regular list of lists.

Comment: My guess is that because you were working with lists, and a set of lists is disallowed (lists aren't hashable) then a `listOfLists` or `listOfSets` became an immediate solution for membership testing. I've certainly done that kind of thing before